# Get a registry key value

Tags: c#, .net, registry

I'm trying to retrieve the version of excel from the registry but I have problems using the

`Registry.GetValue(...)`
method

The value I am trying to retrieve is in HKEY_CLASS_ROOT\Excel.Application\CurVer
But I do not know what name to put as a parameter in the GetValue method.

I tried :

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot;
RegistryKey subKey = key.OpenSubKey(@"Excel.Application\CurVer"); 
// Also tried w/o the "\CurVer"
return subKey.GetValue("CurVer");
```

But I keep getting a NullReferenceException on the GetValue

Comment: Note that `key.OpenSubKey` returns an object of the type `RegistryKey` which implements `IDisposable`, so I would recommend that you wrap the call to `OpenSubKey` in a `using` block.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The version number is the default value.

To get this you need:

```
string s = reg.GetValue(null).ToString();
```

Comment: So simple :s thanks. I've even tried "default" or with no parameter but didn't think of null. Need a coffee

Answer (score 1):

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot;  
RegistryKey subKey = key.OpenSubKey(@"Excel.Application\CurVer");   

return subKey.GetValue("");
```